# Removing Carriage Returns from Csv String

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am generating a csv string using pandas as such:
`df.to_csv(sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)`.

I will load the csv in postgres as follows.

```
    COPY table_name FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV,
    DELIMITER ',',
    HEADER FALSE,
    NULL '',
    ENCODING 'utf-8');
```

Occasionally this will fail when there is carriage return present in the csv, which I remove using `csv_str.replace('\r', '')`. However I am not sure if this approach might alter some existing data in the csv by any chance.

Is there a more reliable way to remove any carriage returns? I am fine with losing information about the carriage returns, but I want to preserve as much as possible any other data stored in the csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than stripping the carriage returns from your CSV file, ensure that those fields that contain them are quoted. One way is to just quote all fields:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv(sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Alternatively you can use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to quote only those fields likely to contain `\r`.

One other way is to set the line terminator to `\r\n` (or just `\r`) which will indirectly cause any field that contains `\r` to be quoted. This might be preferred because only those individual "cells" that require it are quoted:

```
df.to_csv(sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, line_terminator='\r\n')
```

Comment: I've tried all three methods, and only the one using `line_terminator` seems to work, the rest cause all null to be quoted and undistinguishable from empty strings. However I would prefer the quote method if possible. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You could try changing the NULL representation to another string, e.g. `\N` using `na_rep='\N'` and then `NULL '\N'` in the `COPY` command, but unfortunately pandas quotes the `\N` and then `COPY` doesn't recognise the value as a NULL. So I think that the answer is no, and you will have to set `line_terminator`.